# Write file with line breaks

Tags: ruby

So I've got a file with the following text:

```
[[[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]]]
```

and I need to break the line after every fourth number, so that it looks like this:

```
[[[[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
[[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
[[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
[[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]]]
```

I could load the file into a new array, make it to a string, then use:

```
.delete("[]").delete(" ").split(",").map(&:to_i)
```

and use:

```
.each_slice(4) { |a| p a }
```

to get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But I don't know, how to write these lines back to the file, with the line break. I need the file to load into another program, which deletes every bracket, so the output above works fine.

Is there a way to solve it with "\n"?

PS: This is my first post, after founding so much help for my projects on this website.

Comment: `f.puts "anything"`

Comment: That did not work for me, because I need a line break after every fourth number in the file. The answer gives me a line break after every number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about the nesting of arrays from input, you could do the following:

```
arr = [[[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]]]
puts arr.flatten.each_slice(4).map(&:to_s).join("\n")
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
  '[1, 2]',
  '[1, 2]',
  '[1, 2]',
]

File.open('output.txt', 'w') do |f|
  data.each do |string| 
    f.puts string
  end
end

$ cat output.txt
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: That did not work for me, the output is like the answer above.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
arr = [[[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]]]

> arr.flatten(2).each { |string| p sting.flatten }
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```